# React onchange function not working

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react js, i am trying to do a TODO app, but i couldn't able to fix this issue, onchange function is not working properly and browser shows no error.

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
      tasks: [
          {'task':"send resume to ramesh hr",'isChecked':'false'},
      ]
    }
//this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   }

    handleCheckBox(e){
      console.log("dada");
    }
    onChange(e) {
       //Your change code here!!
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul className="task-list">
          {
            this.state.tasks.map(function(el, i) {  
              return (<li key={i}>
                      <div className="content">
                          <div className="tick">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked={el.isChecked}  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>)
            })  
          }
        </ul>
  );
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you saying that it's not working? errors? what is currently happening? you need to specify it

Comment: You're not doing anything inside `onChange()`—therefore nothing happens.

Comment: Also, `this` does not refer to the component inside your `map`, you can use a fat arrow function (`this.state.tasks.map((el, i) => {...}`) to fix it, or bind `this`.

Comment: @Roljhon nothing is visible after put this onchange code

Comment: @FabianSchultz sorry i am not getting you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes**:

*You are using callback methods with map, so you need to maintain the context also to use `this` keyword inside map body, use `.bind(this)` with callback method or to avoid this kind of mistake use arrow function it will do this job for, you don't need to worry about maintaining the context.

*You are using array of object, so use [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), to follow the rule that we should not do any changes directly in state variable.

*You need to pass index of checkbox in onchange method to toggle the state of that checkbox.

Check the working code:

```js
class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
      tasks: [
          {'task':"send resume to ramesh hr",'isChecked':'false'},
      ]
    }
//this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   }

    handleCheckBox(e){
      console.log("dada");
    }
    onChange(i, e) {
       let tasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks));
       tasks[i].isChecked = e.target.checked;
       this.setState({tasks});
       console.log('clicked');
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul className="task-list">
          {
            this.state.tasks.map((el, i) => {  
              return (<li key={i}>
                      <div className="content">
                          <div className="tick">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked={el.isChecked}  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, i)}/>
                            {el.task}
                          </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>)
            })  
          }
        </ul>
  );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ToDoList/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

**Note**: Don't use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.tasks))`, i just used that to tell you, you should not do any changes in state variable directly. You need to use [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) or other more efficient way to do the same task.